# jQuery toggling a class to remove highlight

Tags: jquery, html, css, events

This should be a very basic fix.  Im wanting to remove the selected class from when clicking on an already highlighted button.  I would like for only one button to be highlighted at any given time.

http://jsfiddle.net/7wy7sjm5/1/

EDIT:  The reason I have the remove class for all of them to execute first is because when one is clicked, I would only like for that one to be highlighted, and not have the previous clicked ones still highlighted.  And when clicking on the same button that is already highlighted, would like to remove the highlight.  Hope this makes sense.

```
$(".details-btn").on("click", function(){
var $this = $(this);
//Add/Remove selected for button
$(".details-btn").removeClass("selected");
$this.toggleClass("selected");});
```

Answer (score 1):

The $('.details-btn') passes an array of all the elements with that class and removes the class, then adds the class to the clicked element.

The table element is also listening for any clicks with the selector '.details-btn'. $(this) will always be the element that triggered the event.

```
$("table").on("click", ".details-btn", function(){
   $('.details-btn').removeClass('selected'); 
   $(this).addClass('selected');

});
```

Comment: Yes, however, I am only wanting one to be highlighted at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Use addClass instead of toggleClass, that should fix it :)

removeClass already removed the class from all buttons, so you only need to add the class to "this" button.

```
$(".details-btn").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //Add/Remove selected for button
    $(".details-btn").removeClass("selected");
    $this.addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(".details-btn").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".details-btn").removeClass("selected"); // remove class from all buttons
    $(this).addClass("selected");     // add class to currently clicked button
});
```